# Custom List Button on Related List not functioning in Community (Napili Template)

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, related-list, community, napili

I have a button on a Related List that is working fine in Classic, but while using within my Community, clicking the button does not invoke the Visualforce page. Are there any settings that I might have missed or any issues with this?

The button is on 'Items' as 'Edit Items'

[image]

[image]

Comment: are there any errors in the console? what about the network tab, can you include some debugging information? here is some useful information on debugging lightning https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/debug_intro.htm

Comment: Remember that Napili runs in Lightning so the VF page needs to be lightning enabled.

Comment: @glls - I enabled debug mode and installed the lighnting inspector. When i'm in the lightning tab and click this button, the only transaction that happens is (ltng:interaction) and that's it. Doesn't look like it is actually doing anything. If I do the same while in Lightning, I get the following https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/sh/31af1bda-44d8-400a-a0f0-a5302bc6beea/2be47a5c4079237ed5e6704983f1b4dd

Comment: @DaveHumm I doubled checked this, it is

Comment: I am getting same issue! @csakon did you get any workaround?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this please? I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

A likely cause is that the Visualforce page is not enabled for lightning and mobile. Napili and the other new templates run within lightning framework unlike the old Visualforce and tabs communities.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce list buttons are not supported in Communities.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_use_visualforce.htm&type=0